# Strategies for managing sorted lists in Firebase

Tags: firebase

If I had a master list of a million items, and another list of a million users, and each user had a custom sorted subset of 50 items, the immediate way to model that would be something like:

```
items
    [itemID] : { name : 'aaa', description : 'bbb', ... }
    ...

users
    [userID1] : {  
        name : 'john', 
        token : 'xyz',
        sortedItems : {
            itemID1 : xx,
            itemID2 : xx,
            ...
        } 
    }
```

Each user would get their own collection of sortedItems in whatever order is needed. The problem with this is that you have to have multiple requests per item to get the full item data. After handling updates to the sorted list, you then you need to query the master list to get the item data. Not a big deal, but is this recommended?

Another strategy would be to duplicate the item data in both the master list and sub-lists (or get rid of master list). That way all the data is right there when you need it. The obvious problem with that is synchronization. What happens if a property of an item changes? You'd have to loop through every user's sortedItems list and update each instance - a recipe for serious data inconsistencies.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can check out my github project for some examples of using indices like this one. http://zenovations.github.io/FirebaseIndex/

Comment: Very interesting project! That is literally exactly what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the recommend method. De-normalization is very common in scalable systems and should work well for your use case.

I would recommend duplicating the keys only, and not the data. That way you don't have a synchronization issue and everyone will be sharing one master state. You will incur an extra roundtrip when loading each item, but note that Firebase is pretty smart about handling large numbers of callbacks and caching updates, so I suspect you'll find it's still quite fast.